# Very minor code optimisation

Tags: java

```
  while (i < a.size() && value2.substring(0, prefix.length()).compareTo(prefix) == 0) {
        value2 = a.get(i);

        if (value2.endsWith(suffix)) {
            counter++;
            setter = true;

        }

        i++;

    }
```

I was just wondering if there was a way to avoid using the get() method twice in my code. My problem right now is that I need to assign value 2 before so that my while loop works but I also need to update it within the while loop.

Comment: You can have in-line assignment inside your `while` condition.

Comment: This is in fact only once... because one statement is outside while and the other is within while which is called during iteration and not the outside one...

Comment: @PM 77-1 Thank you. Could you demonstrate how I would do that with my while loop?

Comment: @Ahmad The first index is looked up twice.

Comment: will see later....   but i will say , just see "I need to assign value 2 before so that my while loop works" you can use do-while which will execute at least once and then check the condition....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        while(i <a.size()){
            value2 = a.get(i);
            if(value2.substring(0,prefix.length()).compareTo(prefix)!=0){
                break;
            }
            if(value2.endsWith(suffix)){
                counter++;
                setter = true;

            }
            i++;
       }
```

Comment: This is  the easiest one to understand thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is what you need:

```
for (String value : a) {
        if (!value.startWith(prefix)) break;
        if (value.endsWith(suffix)) {
            counter++;
            setter = true;
        }
    }
```

If a is not iterable:

```
        while(i < a.size()){
        String value = a.get(i);
        if (!value.startsWith(prefix))
            break;
        if(value.endsWith(suffix)){
            counter++;
            setter = true;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is neat. Would this work with a list of value? with changing indexes?

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice. As i'm not using an actual list type a class that a lecturer made using a different typed class it's not working. It's class work where i have to use classes given to me so I'm not able to use actual List types..

Comment: Then you can only use a while loop, but I think maybe you can use startWith for string prefix comparison.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to a Python issue about [not being able to assign in conditions](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-can-t-i-use-an-assignment-in-an-expression.htm); we can use the `while(true) if () break;` idiom instead - actually, we cannot do `while (true)` as we'll crash on `i == a.size()`, so instead we'll split the code into a `while` and an `if`:

```
while (i < a.size())
{
    String value2 = a.get(i);
    if (value2.substring(0, prefix.length()).compareTo(prefix)==0)
    {
        if(value2.endsWith(suffix)){
            counter++;
            setter = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

(Oh, and please try to format your code with regular indentation levels; it makes things so much easier to follow for not just us, but you too.)

---

Following on from comments below, one can also do the shorter, but in my opinion harder to read:

```
String value2;
while (i < a.size() && (value2 = a.get(i)).substring(0, prefix.length()).compareTo(prefix)==0)
{
    if(value2.endsWith(suffix))
    {
        counter++;
        setter = true;
    }
    i++;
}
```

In this case, with the assignment in the middle of the second expression, I think it is easy for the reader to overlook.

Comment: Can you please provide a reference for not being able to assign in conditions for Java?

Comment: @PM77-1 You can of course in Java - it's just that I was looking at that Python page yesterday so I remembered their `while True: if : break` idiom to avoid double assignments.

Comment: If you do in-line assignment it will be the only one.  No need to complicate the code.

Comment: @PM77-1 We're getting into a style argument, but I've edited the answer to add an in-line example, but I think it looks worse. But on the other hand, I've just realised my version will crash when `i == a.size()`... Let me edit that too.

Comment: @KenY-N thanks for the example on how to use in-line assignments. You're right in this example it's harder to follow but it's still very useful information for the future.

Answer (score 1):

in java8, you can use `stream` like this：

```
    counter = a.stream()
           .filter(s -> s.startsWith(prefix))
           .filter(s -> s.endsWith(suffix))
           .count();
    setter = counter > 0;
```